# video on ended plays again from start instead of stop/pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

```
<video class='vsingle' id='vsingle' src='ph/video.mp4' poster='ph/vposter.jpg' controls></video>
```

**js**

```
$('#vsingle').on('ended',function(){
    $(this)[0].load();
});
```

This code results in playing video again from start
I want just to reload it, so starting poster to be visible and not to play
How can I to this ?

I also tried this, vithout success

```
$(this)[0].load();
$(this)[0].pause();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MDN Docs @https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/load:

> The HTMLMediaElement method load() resets the media element to its initial state and begins the process of selecting a media source and loading the media in preparation for playback to begin at the beginning.

Try using [currentTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime), like this:

```
$(this)[0].pause();
$(this)[0].currentTime = 0;
```

**Edit:**

Check if maybe there other event listeners (causing play to begin)?

I just tried to reproduce your code here and simply adding:

```
video.addEventListener('ended', () => {   video.load(); })
```

gave the expected result, and the video did not start auto-playing.

Comment: tried, the same result

Comment: Weird, I just tried to reproduce your code here and simply adding `video.addEventListener('ended', () => {
  video.load();
})` gave the expected result, and the video did not started playing. Are there other event listeners?

Comment: Found it! There is another event listener, set to `canplay`, the snippet is: `vsingle.on('canplay', function(){ vsingle.trigger('play'); })` I removed it and `load()` behaved as expected